# Convergence to $\frac{1}{\pi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, pi

Mathematicians of all times found approximations for the value of $\pi$ using infinite sums. But I was asking to myself: is there any infinite sum that approximates $\frac{1}{\pi}$?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\pi}+0+0+0+\cdots$$

Comment: There are two on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

Comment: Look up Ramanujan series for $1/\pi$.

Comment: Yep, I see. Is there any proof to this result of Ramanujan?

Comment: Look at the power series for $\sin{x}/x$.

Comment: @RonGordon Lot's of power series with non-constant leading term, divided by $x$ shall serve the purpose.

Comment: I bet you will love this site: https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0013

Comment: @Zev Hilarious. Not. Good thing there isn't downvote on comments, huh?

Comment: @Bill: Besides its obvious humor value, the actual point is to demonstrate that further thought needs to go into specifying what is desired. ([Here's another example](http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20110408.gif).) What does it mean for a series to approximate something? What kinds of terms should be allowed (only rational numbers, perhaps)? Those are important things for the OP to consider and explain.